# How to extract phrases that are part of a list in a string

Tags: string, google-sheets

For example, I have a list of phrases/words ("boy, a guy, tree") and I want them to be the result if written in a string and remove duplicate

Desired Outcome:
Input: boy girl a tree a guy and a boy
Output: boy tree a guy (in any particular order, I don't mind)

Input: boy boy boy boy boy
Output: boy

Input: girl boy girl boy a guy
Output: girl boy a guy (in any particular order, I don't mind)

Input: a guy girl very handsome girl tricky question
Output: a guy girl

Comment: How are we supposed to differ between `a guy` and `a`, `guy`?

Comment: @Wiktor  Could you explain why you're removing regex tag from these questions, when the OP is clearly asking  for regex?

Comment: @TheMaster OP has no regex issue. There is no regex in the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm not sure I agree with the reasoning here. Yes, it's "gimme the code" question. But the question is asking for regex. I think you can downvote it  and/or vote to close it(if any close reasons apply), but I don't think  removing the tag is justified.

Answer (score 0):

You can `filter` the target `words` and on the `filter` callback, you check if the `str` includes each word of these, and after filteration then `join` with a white space.

```js
const words = ['boy', 'girl', 'a guy'];

function getWords(str) {
  return words.filter(w => str.includes(w)).join(' ');
}

console.log(getWords("boy boy boy boy boy")) // boy

console.log(getWords("girl boy girl boy a guy Output: girl boy a guy")) // girl boy a guy

console.log(getWords("a guy girl very handsome girl tricky question")) // a guy girl
```

Comment: OP asked for regex

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
=TRIM(JOIN(" ",BYROW({"boy","girl","a guy","tree"};LAMBDA(R,IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,R))))))
```

[here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gwdOpCyaXs6WyhKZMHwniN1wbkdOIB7qLmn4b2iLovU/edit?usp=sharing) the test sheet, you can choose words in a first range.

In your examples *girl* is not declared and not even extracted .